Terminology for removing edges and vertices from graphs
I have seen various definitions related to removing vertices or edges from connected graphs and wondering if I could clarify them.
A connected graph $G$ is called one-vertex irreducible (1VI) if it cannot be edge-disconnected by removing a single vertex.
The formal definition for a graph being core or one-particle irreducible (1PI) which I am using can be found in Definition 2.4 of this article.
Is being a core subgraph a weaker condition than being 1VI?

It might be helpful to give the definition of 1PI, as I, for one, am not familiar with it. Your definition of core subgraph is a little unclear (do you mean some edge or any edge when you write an edge and I am not sure exactly what you mean by loop number). Perhaps you could give a specific reference or references to the sources that are giving you trouble.

@RobArthan I have now added a specific reference with the definition in question.

Do you have a few example graphs and decide for each one if they are 1VI and 1PI?

Thanks for supplying the reference.

The usual terminology for these (see, for example, Wikipedia's glossary, as well as the Wikipedia links below, or standard graph theory textbooks such as the ones by Bondy and Murty, by Diestel, or by West) is:

A "1VI" graph is called 2-vertex-connected or occasionally just 2-connected if there is no ambiguity. Generally, biconnected refers to the same notion, but some sources make a minor distinction, saying that the $2$-vertex complete graph $K_2$ is biconnected, but not 2-vertex-connected.
A connected "1PI" graph is called 2-edge-connected. (More broadly, if each component is $2$-edge-connected, the graph is called bridgeless.)

(The linked definition of 1PI graphs is somewhat different: they are the graphs in which every edge deletion reduces the cycle rank. But an edge deletion reduces the cycle rank if and only if the edge is part of a cycle, which in turn is true if and only if deleting the edge does not increase the number of components.)
All 2-vertex-connected graphs are also 2-edge-connected (with the possible exception of $K_2$, if you consider it to be $2$-vertex connected, and that is one of the reasons why many sources exclude it). In other words, 1VI implies 1PI, or nearly does.
The reverse is not true: for example, take two complete graphs (with at least 3 vertices each) that overlap in a single vertex. In other words, 1PI does not imply 1VI.

Thanks for the definitions.  I have also seen ''biconnected graph'', I assume this is the same as ''2-connected'' ie. 1VI?

Essentially, yes. There are some quibbles about whether the graph with 2 vertices and 1 edge should count, and some authors use "biconnected" and "2-connected" as separate choices that disagree on that graph only.

I don't understand: from the OP's definition of 1VI, a wedge of two triangles (i.e., a bowtie) is 1V1, but it's not 1P1 according to the definition in the article cited: removal of any edge from the wedge reduces the rank of its first homology group from $2$ to $1$

@RobArthan Removing any edge reduces the rank, which is the definition of a graph that is 1P1. (But the bowtie is not 1V1: removing the center vertex disconnects it.)

OK. The bowtie was a bad example. How about two squares that share an edge? (BTW, it would be helpful if you gave a reference for your terminology, which is just as far away from the elementary graph theory that I learnt while studying algebraic topology many years ago.)

@RobArthan I've added references. (Though I suspect part of the trouble is, also, that you learned your elementary graph theory while studying algebraic topology, not while studying graph theory, and these two groups of people don't always speak the same language.) If you have two squares that share an edge, that should be both 1V1 (no vertex deletion disconnects it) and 1P1 (every edge deletion reduces the rank).

Many thanks for the references. I will take a look at them and see if I can get the implications lined up right. I can see already that I was misunderstanding much of your answer.
